# MySql Select daterange with datetime using html date input

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I am using MySqli for a MySql server. I am setting up a form in which the user can enter a date using the date input type in a html form:

```
<div class="ElHolder">
    <form action="productionOutput.php" method="get">
        <input type="date" name="packHistDate" required>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

I am then using php to get the date entered and am trying to use it in my sql query. I set `$packHistDate = $_GET["packHistDate"]` earlier in my code.

```
        $sql = "SELECT 
                    PRODUCTS.ProductId,
                    PRODUCTS.Name,
                    DATE(PACKING_QUEUE.DatePackFinished) AS \"DateFinished\",
                    PACKING_QUEUE.Packets,
                    PACKING_QUEUE.SizeCode,
                    PACKING_QUEUE.RunSize,
                    BATCHES.BatchId
                FROM PACKING_QUEUE
                    JOIN BATCHES ON BATCHES.BatchId = PACKING_QUEUE.BatchId
                    JOIN PRODUCTS ON PRODUCTS.ProductId = BATCHES.ProductId
                WHERE PACKING_QUEUE.Status = 6 AND PACKING_QUEUE.DatePackFinished BETWEEN ".$packHistDate." AND NOW()
                ORDER BY PACKING_QUEUE.DatePackFinished DESC";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if (!$result) {
            printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);
        }
```

PACKING_QUEUE.DatePackFinished is DATETIME and I think that is where the error arises from. However I don't get any error message the code executes but all dates get returned.

I have tried using DATE() to convert them all into dates but that still doesn't work.

Any help is greatly appriciated

UPDATE: adding in single quotes around the `".$datePackFinished."` so it was like `'".$datePackFinished."'` fixed it!

Comment: Were you ever curious about the `$packHistDate` contents?

Comment: echo your query and check

Comment: `$packHistDate` must be `YYYY-MM-DD` format. Check it first. I think it also must be quoted.

Comment: When I `echo $packHistDate` I get "2016-08-21", so html is formatting the date for me, but it doesn't work within my query

Comment: So... `echo $sql;`

Comment: You should add an answer if you have found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding in single quotes around the `".$datePackFinished."` so it was like `'".$datePackFinished."'` fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

I simply change the date part. Just alter the date part like

```
BETWEEN NOW() AND ".$packHistDate."
```

and for my it worked.

or you can do it by adding extra single quotes

```
BETWEEN NOW() AND '".$packHistDate."'
```

Comment: When I try that nothing gets returned at all.

Comment: I think you need to give extra single quote, without single quote i get all data, but using this get exact result
 ' ".$packHistDate." ' AND NOW()